# Gson 2.2.2 Json custom JsonWriter for JsonElement to avoid escaping String?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a use case where I have a pre-escaped valid string to be returned as a JsonElement. However, the JsonElement internally using the JsonWriter would parse through the string to attempt doing string escaping / character replacement.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java

private void string() method

I would like to avoid doing this for performance reasons as my String element is pre-escaped.

I did a search and found this use case to be similar:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=239

Although the solution in the above link would work with gson1.5, the Escaper class has been removed in the latest gson (2.2.2).

How can I extend the JsonElement (or the JsonWriter internal to it) such that I can avoid the JsonWriter string replacement overhead for a specific Type?

Comment: You fixed this or still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
OutputStream rawStream = ...
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(rawStream, "UTF-8"));

... /* normal gson/json usage */

// about to write object including a base 64 big byte[]
/* don't using binding API for images, too big, too slow */
String b64 = Base64.encodeToString(blob, Base64.NO_WRAP);
writer.beginObject();
writer.flush();
/* gson.JsonWriter doesn't understand the string is b64 encoded,
   and hence doesn't need escaping, so lets use an ASCII encoder
   for a little while
*/
OutputStreamWriter asciiWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(rawStream, "ASCII");
asciiWriter.write(
    String.format("\"id\": \"%d\", \"raw\": \"", param.id)
);
asciiWriter.write(b64);
asciiWriter.write("\" ");
asciiWriter.flush();
writer.endObject();
```

While not 'in API' this should continue to work given that

- Beginning a JSON object is a known point (e.g. no 'state' to keep after the {)
- ending a empty JSON object is also a known point ('can just put the brace })
- Which in turn means writing valid JSON as ascii in the mean time should not need to impact state of JSON writer.

Note, I have tested this, it works, and is significantly faster than using JsonWriter.value(String value).